# isEmpty was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new in flutter.

I want to get data from API and handle if it's empty

so this is my code

```
setState(() {
  var content = json.decode(res.body);
  data = content['results'];
});


data.isEmpty ? Column(children: <Widget>[
      Text(
        'your inbox is empty',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0, color: Colors.blueGrey),
      )
    ],): ListView.builder(
      itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(
            data[index]['body'],
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          )
        );
      },
    )
```

but it's throwing an error

```
The getter 'isEmpty' was called on null
```

how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data variable is null. Your can check it like this:

```dart
data?.isEmpty != false ? [empty] : [not empty]
```

So it's true when data is null OR when data.isEmpty is true, and it's only false when data.isEmpty is false.

Answer (score 1):

Your (data variable) is null so when you call data.isEmpty it throws an exception ,

try to check it's not null first